# Where can I find documentation for Net::Libnet?

Tags: perl, network-programming, libnet

Could someone provide some links to additional documentation or tutorials for the CPAN module [Net::Libnet](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Net::Libnet)?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with `Net::Libnet`? This module only had one release in 2007 and I doubt that any good use can be made out of it.

Comment: am searching for opensource packet creation and injection library which os independent and works in perl if you have another documentation in addition to the cpan about this library you are welcome to share

Answer (score 2):

There's a link to the module's homepage right in CPAN: http://www.packetfactory.net/libnet/ (although this link doesn't work -- the site has moved to http://libnet.sourceforge.net/)

What details are you looking for?

Comment: Some examples about using this library in perl in addition to the documentation in the  CPAN homepage –

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't yet found what you are looking for, you could attempt to contact the [module author](http://search.cpan.org/~smpeters/Net-Libnet-0.01_03/lib/Net/Libnet.pm#AUTHOR) via the email address he provides on CPAN. Perhaps he can share some notes or more sample code with you.